# Angular 13 - own built libraries with nested sub-libraries, their paths and dependencies

Tags: angular

After researching the topic including many contradicting and often not working tutorials the simplest solution for nested sub-library was to follow the [doc of ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md)
All appears working fairly simply if the positioning of the config. files is correct as per the documentation. Here is the working arrangement of an own sample library with sub-library.

Commands:

```
ng new ang-wksp --create-application false --prefix my-org
cd ang-wksp
ng generate library @my-org/lib-prim --prefix my-org
```

Create dir:

```
projects\my-org\lib-prim\prim-sublib01
```

Commands:

```
ng generate module    ../../prim-sublib01/src/lib/modules/prim-sublib01 --project @my-org/lib-prim
ng generate component ../../prim-sublib01/src/lib/components/prim-sublib01 --project @my-org/lib-prim --export --module ../../prim-sublib01/src/lib/modules/prim-sublib01/prim-sublib01.module.ts
ng generate service   ../../prim-sublib01/src/lib/services/prim-sublib01 --project @my-org/lib-prim
```

Create / add 3 config. files that define the sub-library:

IMPORTANT: Note the location/path of each file !!!

```
projects\my-org\lib-prim\prim-sublib01\src\public-api.ts
projects\my-org\lib-prim\prim-sublib01\ng-package.json
projects\my-org\lib-prim\prim-sublib01\package.json
```

Content of file - public-api.ts:

```
    export * from './lib/services/prim-sublib01.service';
    export * from './lib/components/prim-sublib01/prim-sublib01.component';
    export * from './lib/modules/prim-sublib01/prim-sublib01.module';
```

Content of file - ng-package.json:

```
    {
      "$schema": "../../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
      "dest": "../../../../dist/my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01",
      "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
      }
    }
```

Content of file - package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "@my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^13.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^13.1.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
      }
    }
```

Modify file (workspace dir) tsconfig.json:

```
. . .
"baseUrl": "./",
. . .
"paths": {

  "@my-org/lib-prim": [
    "dist/my-org/lib-prim/my-org-lib-prim",
    "dist/my-org/lib-prim"
  ],
  "@my-org/lib-prim/*": [
    "projects/lib-prim/my-org-lib-prim/*",
    "projects/lib-prim"
  ],
  
  "@my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01": [
    "dist/my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01/my-org-lib-prim-prim-sublib01",
    "dist/my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01"
  ],
  "@my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01/*": [
    "projects/lib-prim/prim-sublib01/my-org-lib-prim-prim-sublib01/*",
    "projects/lib-prim/prim-sublib01"
  ]
},

. . .
```

Command:

```
ng build @my-org/lib-prim
```

Now in an app I can import statically:

```
import { LibPrimModule } from '@my-org/lib-prim';
import { PrimSublib01Module } from '@my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01';
```

or:

```
import { LibPrimModule } from 'projects/my-org/lib-prim/src/public-api';
import { PrimSublib01Module } from 'projects/my-org/lib-prim/prim-sublib01/src/public-api';
```

I have some related questions for this arrangement.

1. Is this a good recommended practice for library/sub-library arrangements (any potential pitfalls)?
2. Can I remove the peerDependencies: @angular/common and @angular/core in package.json of my sub-library? It seams to be working both ways - with or without - where I think the parent library supplies the dependency.
3. What is the best way in tsconfig.json file to configure the:  *"paths": { ... }*  so it is easy to navigate to and debug library / sub-library modules during the development stage, while implementing it easily for production ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logical answer to question # 2:

*Can I remove the peerDependencies: @angular/common and @angular/core in package.json of my sub-library? It seams to be working both ways - with or without - where I think the parent library supplies the dependency.*

I found it [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1187/npm-peer-dependencies):

" . . .
Yes, we can usually assume that for our Angular specific library the Workspace will already have the Angular packages available. Hence, technically we wouldn’t need to bother adding them to our list of dependencies.

However, we really do want to tell the developer which Angular versions our library is compatible with. So I recommend the following approach:

Add at least angular/core for the compatible Angular version to your peerDependencies.

This way developers will see a warning if they try to use your Angular 7 library in their Angular 6 project. Don’t bother adding the other Angular packages. You can assume if they have angular/core, they have the other Angular libraries.
. . . "